# Differential Equation, phase curve.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x:I \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^n$ be a solution defined on an interval $I \subset \mathbf{R} $. Consider the ODEs

$$
\dot{x} = x,
$$
$$
\dot{y} = ky,
$$

where $k$ is a constant. Is the curve given by

$$
\left | y \right | = C\left | x \right |^k
$$

a phase curve of the ODE? $C$ is a constant. A phase curve in $\mathbf{R}^n$ is the image $x(I)$ where $x$ is a solution to the ODE.

I don't know how to start attempting to prove the phase curve.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- $(1)$ Can you solve the System of equations? You should get: $x(t) = c_1 e^{-t},~ y(t) = c_2 e^{k t}$
- $(2)$ Draw phase portraits for various $k$
- $(3)$ Given $\left | y \right | = C\left | x \right |^k$, can you plug in the $x(t)$ solution you got in from $(1)$ and see what that gives you and if it looks like the $y(t)$ solution? In other words, compare the $\left | y \right |$ to $y(t)$ from $(1)$.

**Update**

The first graphic is the direction field, with phase plots superimposed for $k = 1$  (a positive value) and the second is for $k = -2$ (a negative value). These are intended to help you understand the solution approach.

[image]

[image]

Regards

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "phase portrait"? It's not the same as a vector field is it?

Comment: @Bunnyhouse: see updates in answer.

Comment: Nice direction curves. +

Comment: @BabakS. Thank you! I am trying to do better at providing guidance and hints, without outright answering, but it is difficult! Regards

Comment: You're doing a good job with guidance and hints! +1